# Why is $\text{Gal}(K/k) \cong \text{Gal}(K(\omega)/k(\omega))$ with $\omega \notin K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The situation is as follows:

$K$ is the splitting field of $\; x^3+px+q \in k[x]$ and $ K(\omega)$ is the field over which $\; x^3-1$ splits.

That's probably one of those things you just see, but I as a beginner haven't got the slightest idea how to show $\text{Gal}(K/k) \cong \text{Gal}(K(\omega)/k(\omega))$. $\omega$ is a root of $x^3-1$ and $\omega \notin K$.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat high-brow explanation comes from the theory of linearly disjoint extensions. Surely that theory is overkill for the purposes of your question, but it's past midnight and I need to wake up in six hours, so...

Here $K/k$ and $k(\omega)/k$ are both Galois extensions of $k$ (assuming $6\cdot 1_k\neq 0_k$). The assumption $\omega\notin K$ implies that the two extensions intersect trivially, $K\cap k(\omega)=k$. For two Galois extensions this implies that the two extensions are linearly disjoint. This has many consequences, for example it implies that $Gal(K(\omega),k)$ is a direct product of $Gal(K(\omega)/K)$ and $Gal(K(\omega)/k(\omega))$. Your claim follows from this by applying [the parallelogram rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem) (aka the second isomorphism theorem) and basic facts from Galois theory.

If you don't know about linearly disjoint field extensions, then I recommend that you study [Pete L. Clark's lecture notes on Field Theory](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/FieldTheory.pdf). I once wrote [a quick-and-dirty intro to the topic](https://users.utu.fi/lahtonen/linearly_disjoint.pdf) that also suffices here. Pete has put a couple orders of magnitude more effort into his notes, and it shows.

Comment: Hoping to extend this answer with a simpler argument covering the case that interests you.

Comment: You're right Jyrki, I made a mistake. Here it is : K contains the quadratic subfield  L= k(u^3, v^3) , but as you say, K in general is not L(u) nor L(v), one must take a combination of u and v. My "sin" comes from my bad rememberance of the Cardano formulas. The true lesson of this is that I should have come back to Galois, viz. give a resolution of S_3 and check the corresponding subfields.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks, another angle is always a good thing. Up to now , I haven't come across linearly disjoint extentions, since I'm a total beginner. But I will definitely look into the matter when I feel ready for it.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd roots complex roots of unity are $1$, $j$, $j^2$, so the extension $k(j)$/$k$ is galois of degree $2$ (you must assume that $K$ is not of characteristic $3$) . Let $a$ be a root of the given cubic, supposed to be irreducible (if it were reducible, the problem would not make sense). Then $k(a)$/$k$ is of degree $3$, hence the composite extension $k(a, j)$ has degree  $6$ over $k$ . But the roots of the cubic are given by well known formulae  which show that the splitting field $K$ is $K$ = $k$(a, cubic root of D), where D is the discriminant  $4 p^3 - 27 q^2$ . Hence $K$ contains $k(a, j)$. Since Gal(K/k) is a subgroup of $S_3$, we conclude that $K$ = $k(a, j)$. The rest of the proof is obvious, because $K$ = $k(a)$($j$) = $k(j)$($a$) .

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but $\omega$ (your $j$) is not in $K$, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why do you think so ? I gave the argument of the cubic root of the discriminant.

Comment: Hmm, then I don't understand your argument :) - Why does $K$ contain $k(a,j)$?

Comment: This comes, as I said, from the explicit formulae (Cardano ?) giving the rootsof the cubic. I don't remember them in detail (no need for them !), but the mere explanation of the method should convince you. It consists in putting x = u + v, and getting by brute force calculations u^3 + v^3 and u^3.v^3 in terms of p and q. So you get u^3 and v^3 as roots of a second degree equation . The roots of the cubic itself are obtained by taking cubic roots, so combining them you get j.

Comment: Hmm. You seem to be implying that $j$ (or $\omega$, or $(-1+i\sqrt3)/2$) will always be in the splitting field as a consequence of Cardano's formula. This is not true. For example it is easy to write down irreducible cubics with integer coefficients such that all the roots are real. Hence all the numbers of the splitting field will be real as well, so $\omega$ does not belong to the splitting field of such a cubic.

Comment: What does hold is that a root extension, $L(\root3\of a)/L$, $a\in L$ not a third power, is a Galois extension if and only if $L$ contains a primitive third root of unity. Cardano's formula is in some sense about producing a root tower extension containing the solution. This looks easier when the base field contains $\omega$. Also note that the entities $u$ and $v$ appearing in Cardano's formula are not in the splitting field. Only the combinations $u+v,\omega u+\omega^2v$ and $\omega^2u+\omega v$ are in the splitting field (those are the zeros).

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm interested in the isomorphy in question. Then one can assume that $\omega$ is in the base field.

Answer (score 1):

To Miriam's intention, allow me to summarize the discussion about the roots of the cubic f($X$) = $X^3$ + p$X$ + q (although it goes beyond her original question). I keep all my previous notations and I assume that k is of characteristic different from 2 and 3. Since $S$ := Gal(K/k) is a subgroup of $S_3$ , its order is 3 or 6. In both cases, it contains a unique subgroup $C$ of order 3, generated by the 3-cycle which permutes the 3 roots of the cubic, say *a, b, c.* To distinguish between the two cases, consider the "discriminant", which is here *D* := $((a-b)(a-c)(b-c))^2$, so that k(sqr *D*) is contained in K, and is actually the fixed field of $C$ . Consequently  $S$ = $S_3$ iff  *D* is a square in k (not simply in K ).

Let us now answer the question : when does *j* belong to K ? A simple calculation using the derivative f '($X$) shows that *D* = -(4 $p^3$ + 27 $q^2$). Since k(sqr *D*) is the unique quadratic subextension of K/k (because of the unicity of *C*), *j* belongs to K iff -3 is multiplicatively congruent to *D* modulo a square of k. Another discriminant now comes into play, that is the discriminant of the second degree equation which gives $u^3$ and $v^3$, namely *d* = (27 $q^2$ + 4 $p^3$)/27   (brute force), or *d* =(-$3$). $3^2$. *D* . So *j* belongs to K iff *d* itself is a square in k, which means that $u^3$ and $v^3$ belong to k .

Now I have done my home work !